# Java: returning a list with a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, return

I'm having some difficulty with this for-loop in java:

```
public String[] geefAlleTemplateNamen(String[][] templateLijst){
    for(int i = 0; i < templateLijst.length; i++){
    String lijst[] = {templateLijst[i][0]};
    }
    return lijst;
}
```

When i execute the program, i get the following error:

```
 Mailmatcher.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
                return lijst;
                       ^
  symbol:   variable lijst
  location: class Mailmatcher
1 error
```

I think this is because 'lijst' is declared inside the for loop, so it's unknown outside it, although i think i know what the problem is, i've got no idea how to solve this.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

I used the search allready, but didn't realy find something, this is a school project, so i don't expect pre-made answers.

Thank you!

Comment: _"I think this is because 'lijst' is declared inside the for loop, so it's unknown outside it, although i think i know what the problem is, i've got no idea how to solve this."_ Then declare it outside the loop :). And always prefer `String[] lijst` instead of `String lijst[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the `lijst[]` outside of the loop and fill the array within the loop:

```
String lijst[] = new String[templateLijst.length];
for(int i = 0; i < templateLijst.length; i++){
    lijst[i] = templateLijst[i][0];
}
return lijst;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it, maybe next time i'll have to think a bit more :)

Comment: You could also use an enhanced for loop here.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer from kocko, it's because the scope of the list is confined to within the loop.  Which will cause two problems,

1. The list gets redeclared as a new empty list for each iteration of the loop (wiping out any previously stored data)
2. The return is outside of the loop, so it can't access the list, it pretty much no longer exists once your code completes the loop and moves on.

So yes, declare the list before the loop.